# CSS Grid, mis imagenes se enciman unas con otras

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid-layout

Buenas tardes estoy trabajando con **CSS grid** y no logro que cada imagen ocupe el tamaño total de la columna que les corresponden, les doy un `"max-width: 100%;"` y designó que son 3 columnas `"grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 250px);"`, si pueden tirarme una soga.

Nota: Tengo que rellenar demasiado espacio con texto para poder mandar la pregunta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>pinterest</title>
    <style>

    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 250px);
        grid-gap: 5px;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .item {
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .item img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .item1 {
        grid-row-end: span 3;
    }
    .item2 {
        grid-row-end: span 2;
    }
    .item3 {
        grid-row-end: span 1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item1">
            <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <img src="imagen2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <img src="imagen3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que veas esto, explica muy bien todo de [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola creo que hay un error en tu seccion de estilos la clase item no esta asignada a ningun elemento, en todo caso lo que estas buscando para ajustar la imagen al espacio es:

```
.container img {
  inline-size: 100%;
}
```

Con esto deberia bastar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

según puedo observar, estás aplicando el "max-width" a la clase "item" y dentro del html no hay ninguna clase que se llame así, lo que debes hacer es reemplazar esa línea de css por esta:

Codigo CSS:

```
.item1 img,.item2 img,.item3 img {

      max-width: 100%;

    }
```